# multiprocessing stuck infinetly

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to build a vector store from my data and I have a large amount of data so automatically I thought about multiprocessing

```
def multiprocess_data(df):
    vector_store = torch.zeros(len(df), 1542)
    for index, row in train.iterrows():
       vector=get_features(row)
       vector_store[index] = vector
       print(index)
    return vector_store
```

```
def main():
    vector_store = None  # Initialize vector_store

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        sub_dataframes = np.array_split(train, 5)
        results = list(executor.map(multiprocess_data, sub_dataframes))
        vector_store = torch.cat(results, dim=0)
        torch.save(vector_store, 'train_vector_store.pt')
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the code works fine without multiprocessing. but with  multiprocessing even with a small portion of data the code remains stuck infinitely
and in the terminal of my kernel, I get this error:
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'multiprocess_data' on <module '**main**' (built-in)>